# Testing tensorflow model in c++: Getting NaN's as an output of tf.nn.softmax

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am struggling when I get the output of the softmax layer in C++. Sometimes it's returning proper values and other times it's just giving me NaN's.
This is a snippet code that I use in order to reproduce the error:

```
cout << x.DebugString() << endl;

std::vector<std::pair<string, Tensor>> inputs = {
    {"x", x},
};

std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;

// Run the session, evaluating our "softmax" operation from the graph
// status = session->Run(inputs, {"softmax_tensor"}, {}, &outputs);
status = session->Run(inputs, {"softmax_tf"}, {}, &outputs);
if (!status.ok()) {
    throw runtime_error(status.ToString());
}

std::cout << outputs[0].DebugString() << std::endl;

outputs.clear();

// Run the session, evaluating our "softmax" operation from the graph
// status = session->Run(inputs, {"softmax_tensor"}, {}, &outputs);
status = session->Run(inputs, {"softmax_tf"}, {}, &outputs);
if (!status.ok()) {
    throw runtime_error(status.ToString());
}

std::cout << outputs[0].DebugString() << std::endl;
```

This is the output I obtain:

```
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,12288] values: [93 69 40]...>
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,2] values: [0.49990705 0.500093]>
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,2] values: [0.49977857 0.50022149]>
y_gender_predictions[0]: Female 
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,12288] values: [112 84 54]...> 
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,2] values: [nan nan]>
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,2] values: [nan nan]>
y_gender_predictions[0]: Male 
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,12288] values: [126 106 73]...> 
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,2] values: [nan nan]> 
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,2] values: [nan nan]>
y_gender_predictions[0]: Male 
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,12288] values: [126 108 81]...> 
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,2] values: [nan nan]> 
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,2] values: [nan nan]>
y_gender_predictions[0]: Male 
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,12288] values: [132 112 85]...> 
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,2] values: [nan nan]> 
Tensor<type: float shape: [1,2] values: [nan nan]>
y_gender_predictions[0]: Male
```

Why am I getting float results only in the first iteration and afterwards NaN's? How can I solve the issue?

As well, I'll be interested to understand why I get different numerical results when I evaluate twice the same image. (It's important to mention that I load the model in Python and I get proper values from the softmax layer. Evaluating the same image I get always the same results.)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you asked me in the jackytung blog. I managed to solve my problem but I am not sure if it helps you I just give you my code maybe you see something helpful.

Here is the python code:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# output Node for prediction in c++ !! Still use softmax_cross_entropy method because it is more stable for training
# prediction = tf.nn.softmax(neural_net_layer)
# use logits (and prediction only for c++)
logits = tf.matmul(neural_net_layer, output_layer['weight'], name="output_TT") + output_layer['bias']
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y_))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cost)

#tupel with (EpochNr, EpochLoss, PredictAccuracy)
train_info = [] 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    accuracy_tmp = 0  # start to save models if accuracy is over x per cent
    epoch_nr_best_model = 0

    for epoch in range(1,hm_epochs+1):
        epoch_loss = 0
        i = 0
        while i < len(train_x):
            start = i
            end = i + batch_size
            batch_x = np.array(train_x[start:end])
            batch_y = np.array(train_y[start:end])

            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y})
            epoch_loss += c
            i += batch_size

        print('Epoch', epoch, '/', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)

        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
        accuracy_val = accuracy.eval({x: test_x, y_: test_y})
        print('Accuracy:', accuracy_val)
```

Maybe a problem could be which layer you define as output layer. For the c++ graph I used the "logits" for output layer but for training in python I used the cost variable.

Here is my cpp code to load the graph:

```
    int number_dim = stream_in[0].dim;
    int number_test = stream_in[0].num; // 4072
    int number_classes = _n_classes;

    tensorflow::Tensor input_tensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape({number_test, number_dim}));
    auto dst = input_tensor.flat<float>().data();
    for (int i = 0; i < stream_in[0].num; i++) {
        std::copy_n(dataptr + i * number_dim, number_dim, dst);
        dst += number_dim;
    }


    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, tensorflow::Tensor>> inputs = {{tokens_io[0], input_tensor}};
    std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
    status = session->Run(inputs, {tokens_io[1]}, {}, &outputs);
    if (!status.ok()) {
        ssi_wrn("status: %s \n", status.ToString().c_str());
        return;
    }

    std::vector<int> number_hits(number_classes, 0);
    for (std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor>::iterator it = outputs.begin(); it != outputs.end(); ++it) {
        auto items = it->shaped<float, 2>({number_test, number_classes});
        for (int i = 0; i < number_test; i++) {
            int arg_max = 0;
            float val_max = items(i, 0);
            for (int j = 0; j < number_classes; j++) {
                if (items(i, j) > val_max) {
                    arg_max = j;
                    val_max = items(i, j);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < number_classes; i++) {
                if (arg_max == i) {
                    number_hits[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < _n_classes; i++) {
        float accuracy = (float) number_hits[i] / number_test;
        ssi_wrn("accuracy for class %s : %f \n", _class_names[i], accuracy);
        _probs[i] = accuracy;
    }
    session->Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I was able to solve the problem. I transformed the data from std::vector<cv::Mat> imgs; to Tensor<DT_FLOAT,TensorShape({amount_of_images, rows, cols, channels})); in a wrong way.